# UICollectionViewController shows up blank/black

Tags: xcode, swift

I am trying to go through some collection view Swift tutorials, but they always show up as blank/black pages as if I have not set an initial view controller. However I have, I only drug out 1 `UICollectionViewController` and set the custom class to my `CollectionViewController`. In this class I implemented the `numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:` method and just to make sure it is working I just returned 3. However when I build and run the project all that should up is a blank/black screen...

Can someone please help? I have been searching through info with no luck...

Comment: Try changing the background color to white instead of default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement at least 3 of the UICollectionViewDataSource methods to get anything to display.

It sounds like you are only telling it how many sections you want, but you have not told it how many views in each section or provided views for it to display.

Try this:

```
    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = UICollectionViewCell()
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

> Don't forget to connect the `delegate` and the `dataSource` to your
>   `viewcontroller`

Easy way to be done is to right click on your `UICollectionView` then drag to the yellow circle on the top of `ViewController`.
Repeat this step twice once choose `dataSource` and once choose `delegate`.

[image: Dragging]
[image: Adding datasource]

Comment: Kegham K. is correct with making sure that your collection view has the dataSource and delegate connected to the View Controller. I found that the conncetion was made better if you "ctrl" click and hold and drop to into your ViewController.swift instead, and set the options to: Outlet/ Name it/ and set to Weak. Hope this further helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:** Click on your view controller in storyBoard.

[image]

**Step 2:** Go to Attributes Inspector( Right hand side in xcode) then change background color from default to white color

[image]

It will show white color.

Comment: Why on earth was this not set as default!? It took me quite some time to find your answer. You saved me quite a bit of time I'd reckon